# How can I get user input for a receipt app in React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I am working on a dummy project for learning purpose. Project is based on making layout of payment receipt, setting up database, get input from user and print the receipt. While designing front end for receipt, I have no idea how to get user input for these fields: Quantity, Description, Amount. I want to make a dynamic structure where user can enter max 7 rows of data in above 3 fields. I have created state variable for above data:

1. itemQuantity 2. itemDescrition 3. itemAmount

So after entering for example:

1  Chair  299 , if user taps return then control should go to next row for data to be inputed for next item. I also want to add print feature to this once data has been entered. Please suggest me how to accomplish this, I am a beginner in react native.[image: The image describes layout of receipt]

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html is what you need

Comment: @Raymond I got that how textinput works, I want to know how can I implement input for multiple items. Suppose I enter item details for 1 item then if I press enter, I want new row to be created to input details for second item. Using text input i can get user input, how to implement that for n items?